# Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object

Tags: ms-access

I have a basic table in an Access database.  In that table, I have a 10-digit numeric field that is stored as Long Text (leading zeros are significant).  I extracted the unique values from that field in the table, and created a new table/field with the same Long Text data type.  When I try to join that field back to the original table, I get the error: Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object.  Is there a work around for this, or a known problem I need to address?

Comment: is this supposed to be tagged mysql? looks like an access problem to me

Comment: Consider changing the data type of the column in the new table to match the column data type in the first one

Comment: A Short Text field will accept a 10-digit string, and support `JOIN` without that complaint.

Comment: What HansUp said.  A Longtext type for a 10 digit string is complete overkill.

Comment: Changing to Short Text worked for this issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use ANSI JOIN instead. It worked for me using

```
        SELECT A.A, B.B, C.C
           FROM aaa AS A, bbb AS B, ccc AS C
       WHERE A.B = B.ID
            AND B.C = C.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Access does not allow Joins based on Long Text fields.  That's the "memo" it is referring to.  I assume Microsoft's rationale is that basing a Join on a paragraph of text is unreasonable.

More here:  https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-cannot-join-on-memo-ole-or-hyperlink-object-when-joining-access-tables

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert the 10 digit numeric field stored as long text to short text. long text is for memo that's why you're getting this error.

I had the same error resulting from LEFT JOINING a msSQLserver table view ON a local msAccess table, the field datatype was nvarchar(80000) in SQLserver table and was auto converted into Memo datatype when linked to msAcces so I had to convert it to nvarchar(25) from SQLserver and refresh the table link to solve the issue.

Comment: It turns out Memo was the name for Long Text in older versions of Access. Seems the name hasn't been updated in the error message, hence why the error is so confusing these days.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to convert the longtext to shorttext and the join will work

Answer (score 0):

Switch it to a short text and then don't forget to hit refresh link or re-import the table and then try to join, it should work. MEMO is a term that Access used to refer to in the previous versions but they didn't update the error statement that shows up.