# Cannot join two tables in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

My query:

```
SELECT 
FROM Penyelaras LEFT JOIN Kursus ON Penyelaras.ICPenyelaras = Kursus.ICPenyelaras;
```

Error message:

> Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object (Penyelaras.ICPenyelaras = Kursus.ICPenyelaras).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVgLD.png)

Comment: The error message appears to be self-explanatory. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921450/cannot-join-on-memo-ole-or-hyperlink-object

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type of field *Kursus.ICPenyelaras* to the data type of field *Penyelaras.ICPenyelaras*.