# Access error "Cannot join on memo, OLE or hyper link objects", even after changing the data type of the fields relevant fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

Originally I was trying to join long text and hyperlink, along with short text etc. The join works when the fields are removed from the query. But after changing the fields (long text to short text & hyperlink to short text) and reintroducing in the query, the query still gives the same error.

```
SELECT products1.*

FROM products1
    LEFT JOIN Products 
        ON (products1.Category = Products.Category)
        AND (products1.[Minimum Reorder Quantity] = Products.[Minimum Reorder Quantity]) 
        AND (products1.Discontinued = Products.Discontinued) 
        AND (products1.[Quantity Per Unit] = Products.[Quantity Per Unit]) 
        AND (products1.[Target Level] = Products.[Target Level]) 
        AND (products1.[Reorder Level] = Products.[Reorder Level]) 
        AND (products1.[List Price] = Products.[List Price]) 
        AND (products1.[Standard Cost] = Products.[Standard Cost]) 
        AND (products1.ID = Products.ID) AND (products1.[Product Name] = Products.[Product Name]) 
        AND (products1.[Product Code] = Products.[Product Code])

WHERE (
    ((Products.ID) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.[Product Code]) Is Null)  
    AND ((Products.[Product Name]) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.[Standard Cost]) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.[List Price]) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.[Reorder Level]) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.[Target Level]) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.[Quantity Per Unit]) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.Discontinued) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.[Minimum Reorder Quantity]) Is Null) 
    AND ((Products.Category) Is Null)
);
```

[Link directs to Image showing Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aboX4.png)

Comment: Can you post the table structure(data types of these columns)

Comment: posted link to Image showing table structure. Description is Long Text so join isn't allowed. However changing the data type to Short Text gives the same error.

Comment: Copy the query to notepad.  Delete the query.  Compact and repair the database.  Exit the database.  Reopen it and create a new query, and paste in the SQL from Notepad.  Access often won't clear out a query's structure when you make table changes like that; somewhere in its memory it still thinks the field is a hyperlink even after you change it.  I've even had occasions where the only way to fix it was to create a whole new DB and import the objects one-at-a-time in the new DB.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. will report the results. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

##### Linked question

This is taken from [Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921450/cannot-join-on-memo-ole-or-hyperlink-object).

##### Answer or workaround?

I do not know why a change of the data type in the database table does not lead to a working code in MS Access, so that I do not know whether this will be a good answer. Perhaps it is just a good workaround, and it worked for me in a setting where I did not want and could not change the data type in the db (and also did not want to make a copied table or a view that changed the data type either).

##### MS Access Type Conversion functions -> CStr() function

You do not need to change the type in the database table. You can leave it as it is and change it with the MS Access functions for TSQL: [Type conversion functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions):

CBool(expression)
CByte(expression)
CCur(expression)
CDate(expression)
CDbl(expression)
CDec(expression)
CInt(expression)
CLng(expression)
CLngLng(expression) (Valid on 64-bit platforms only.)
CLngPtr(expression)
CSng(expression)
CStr(expression)
CVar(expression)

For a text field to work in Access, find the [`CStr()` function]:

> CStr  String  Returns for CStr depend on the expression argument.

It returns [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-data-type).