# MS Access creating query with SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have just recently moved a large file from MS Access to SQL Server Management Studio v18.4

I have been able to successfully create a link between SQL Server and MS Access, but when I run a query between my primary data source and the SQL Server data source I keep getting the following error:

> Microsoft Access
>   Cannot join on Memo, OLE or Hyperlink Object (NTT.LOBBY=DDT.LOBBY).

I had it set to `nvarchar(MAX)` and then changed it to `text`.

but I keep getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Please share the schema of the table you're using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921450/cannot-join-on-memo-ole-or-hyperlink-object)